# Generic "set property" function in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I encountered a problem that I simplified by creating the function below :

```
function setProperty<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
  obj[key] = "hello";
}
```

The code does not compile, `obj[key]` is underlined in red and I get the error :

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.ts(2322)

I understand that it is because of the keyword "extends" but I don't know how to solve my problem.

Can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to solve your problem depending on your usecase. If you just want to set any string as a value to any particular key, you don't need to use generics:

```
function setProperty(obj: Record<string, string>, key: string) {
  obj[key] = "hello";
}
```

However if your object has specific keys and specific values you can use generics like this so the compiler type checks your arguments:

```
function setProperty<T extends Record<string, string>, K extends keyof T, V extends T[K]>(obj: T, key: K, value: V) {
  obj[key] = value
}

type ObjectValue = 'foo' | 'bar'

type A = {
  foo: ObjectValue,
  baz: 'baz'
}

const a: A = {
  foo: 'foo',
  baz: 'baz'
}

setProperty(a, 'foo', 'bar') // works
setProperty(a, 'foo', 'baz') // type error
```

This also has a nice benefit of InteliSense sugsestions.

**EDIT:**

Since OP wanted just to type check the key and set an arbitrary string, this solution should be better:

```
function setProperty<K extends string>(obj: Record<K, string>, key: K) {
  obj[key] = "hello";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't really solve my problem because my goal here is not to have the value as an argument but to be defined in the function as my code shows.

Comment: The first example should work just fine for any `obj` of type `Record<string, string>`. If it doesn't work please specify me the type of `obj` argument that is being passed to the function.

Comment: You're right, the first example works but we lose the type checking on "key" argument and I don't want that.

Comment: Then you can do this and not lose the key type checking:

`function setProperty<K extends string>(obj: Record<K, string>, key: K) {
  obj[key] = "hello";
}`

Comment: Oh nice ! Perfect one. Can you edit your first answer with this ? Then I can accept it

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this will achieve the result you're looking for with your use case, but if you simply want this to compile, you can use a type assertion.

```
function setProperty<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T, key: keyof T) {
  obj[key] = "hello" as T[keyof T];
}
```

`"hello"` has literal type `hello`. The Typescript compiler can see that you want to set a value on `obj`, which has keys with type `keyof T`. It can't infer that type `hello` is of the required type unless you assert it is as above.

However if you want to set the value on `obj[key]` to `hello`, I'd personally use the first approach from Michael Vrana's answer.

Comment: Indeed, we can cast the value but I have the feeling that this is not the clean way. "hello" has the literal type "hello" that extends string. That's why we can do `const str: string = "hello"`. 
Actually `obj[key]` is not of type string but of a type that extends string and that's why that problem happens I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Object.assign`

```js
type StringValue<Obj> = {
    [Prop in keyof Obj]: Obj[Prop] extends string ? Prop : never
}[keyof Obj]

/**
 * Obtain all keys with string value
 * Only these keys are allowed
 */
type Result = StringValue<{ age: number, name: string }> // name

function setProperty<
    Value,
    Obj extends Record<string, Value>
>(obj: Obj, key: StringValue<Obj>) {
    Object.assign(obj, { [key]: 'hello' })
}

const user = {
    age: 42,
    name: 'John',
    surname: 'Doe'
}

setProperty(user, 'name') // ok
setProperty(user, 'surname') // ok ok

setProperty(user, 'age') // expected error, because age is a number
```

With help of `StringValue` utility type, TS will allow only keys with string value.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFoFwTwBwUwAQGUICcCWA7A5gNQIYA2ArnADwDyARgFYB8CAvAgN6gIcIDaACqgPYwEWBAGs4UfgDME1GgF0AXLNq8BMeQjgAPCHEwATAM4IjaLNgQB%20BH0EJlmOADc4qUAF8u4yTLnzwEAB6ACoQ9hCVCHwRIkIxCRMAd3QIAAtTcxwEZyJSCNlMQigEdLgjRB8TfFREOP4kuAMIoMhYRAAlcuJCCCZkLLw88hYEfGw4R2IAWyo3ABoETHxpycyMbI8GIKCllbhAqWJMAGMIdH5MUzgIO3hUaDJ2TgISOHnnjjktXX1jBC6J34qAMZDMG2wi1epDooDoAAp%20LRlHJFj5lCgIdDyHI6ABKVifFQ0OBnAB0%20CMRnQ2EwiNoi1G3gkSgQAHI0nBCIR%20GyEB48Z5AkDMGYEMQKqh%20mwQJwxhNlAAWABMH1lnGWq2UbIAUvw0pg2Wq5UZiKhNWs2QARfhwNlCsAgCq3dRuaDwiULdkWtkEnYIfiiUDOu5uqAeyWLNmm837X0If2BgNBx0h10PcOe1BR8Z2v27HTwM5NLSoATZhBzE74T3yxDoapLGZzdwgIA)

Please try to aboid mutations in TS. See [this](https://catchts.com/mutations) article.