# Make a generic TypeScript function for property/field mapping

Tags: typescript

I want to convert an array of objects, into a set of known properties of a single object.  I have working TypeScript code, but I want to make it into a generic function.  Below is my working code.

global definition...

```
export type Pic = SanityDocument & {
    id: Slug,
    caption: string,
    group: string,
    pic: Image,
}
```

Example code I want to make generic:

```
const pics : Pic[]  = await sanityClient.fetch(`
        *[_type == "pic"]
    `);

// Example type I want to make generic...
type PicMap = {alpha: Pic, bravo: Pic};

// How do I make `PicMap` be a generic I specify
// as part of a function call?
const picMap : PicMap = pics.reduce((acc, pic : Pic) => {
  acc[pic.id.current as keyof PicMap] = pic;
  return acc;
}, {} as PicMap);
```

The above code works. I want to modify the above code so that type `PicMap` becomes generic, so I can re-use this code for other target objects.  How is that done?  There are three scenarios of what I'm looking for:

1. A TypeScript function that allows me to generically replace `PicMap` with something else.  However, the `Pic` type is fixed/required. **This is my minimum requirement**.
2. As before, but the `Pic` type is also generic.
3. A variant of either option #1 or #2, where the `PicMap` type can be declared inline rather than requiring an explicit declaration.

Option #1 is what I absolutely need to fulfill this question.  Options #2 and/or #3 are icing on the cake.

I am intentionally not using `Record<t,k>` for two reasons.  First, I want the `picMap` object properties accessible with auto-complete.  Second, for me it is ok if the source array has objects that don't exist as exposed properties of the final object.  In other words, I am not attempting to limit what properties can be assigned...I am only limiting which properties I can "see" with intellisense. So I don't want a solution [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69106990/generic-set-property-function-in-typescript).

### UPDATE

My own attempt at a solution currently looks like this:

New global definition...

```
type NamedAsset = SanityDocument & {
    id: Slug // has a string property called 'current'
}
```

And then my generic function...

```
export function MapAsset<
   V extends object, 
   K extends NamedAsset, 
   T extends K[]> (items:T) : V {
    const acc = items.reduce((acc, asset:K) => {
        acc[asset.id.current as keyof V] = asset;
        return acc;
    }, {} as V);
    return acc;
}
```

Unfortunately the above has a "Type 'K' is not assignable" error.  However, if the above were working then my example
usage might look like this:

```
// Sample type for array contents...
export type Pic = NamedAsset & {
    caption: string,
    group: string,
    pic: Image,
}

// Just some arbitrary way to fill the array.
const pics : Pic[]  = await sanityClient.fetch(`
        *[_type == "pic"]
    `);

// An arbitrary type of arbitrary declared properties.
type PicMap = {alpha: Pic, bravo: Pic};

const picMap : PicMap = MapAsset(pics);
// Or, alternatively...
const picMap = MapAsset<PicMap>(pics);
```

### UPDATE #2

I asked ChatGPT to solve the error I found in my prior example solution.  What it gave back does work, but it is brain-melting.  It's solution:

```
export function MapAsset<T extends NamedAsset[]>(items:T):
{
    [K in T[number]['id']['current']]: Extract<T[number], {id : {current:K}}>
}
{
    const acc = items.reduce((acc, asset) => {
        acc[asset.id.current] = asset;
        return acc;
    }, {} as any);
    return acc;
}
```

Then to use the above, I do this:

```
type PicMap = {alpha: Pic, bravo: Pic};
const picMap = MapAsset(pics) as PicMap;
```

Having a function whose result I must cast is not what I had in mind.  However, I admit this would be acceptable-ish in the absence of a better answer.  Aside from the need to cast the result, I also don't like that the MapAsset function is surprisingly esoteric.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I made an edit simultaneously with you, which caused yours to be overwritten.  Accident.  However, mostly you just removed the `typescript-generics` tag.  Why?

Comment: What's `SanityDocument` and `sanityClient`?  Could you consolidate the code into a single [mre] without reference to private or third-party code?  The goal is that we could copy and paste your plaintext into our own IDEs and see the issue for ourselves.

Comment: Because it's usless. _"Tags are a means of connecting experts with questions they will be able to answer"_ - generics are _part of_ TypeScript, not  a separate area of expertise. Also the "update" titles are not helpful - write the question for the _next_ viewer, if people want to see how the question developed they can read [the revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77470015/revisions).